# Search tags in mysql table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, tags

I have a table with some submissions, this table has a `tags` field, and I need to search in it.

The data is saved in JSON format in the table, like this: `["basic","example","html","chart"]`

I'm trying to find a way to search all rows in the tags fields, but not sure how it can be done the best way when it is in this format.

The user submits an tag to search, like: `html`, then I need to search all rows for that tag, without to much overhead.

I know most people use to say: what have you tried yourself?
- well, nothing. As I have no clue how to do this, I know how to search in sql and all that. but never tried it in this logic.

Comment: Gotta try this, will it work when the data is in JSON?.. I guess so, `in` searches the whole field.

Comment: @aldrin27 He have the exact opposite scenario you have told. He have no. of values in database not in input tag.

Comment: @Convertor May be Like or FIND_IN_SET will work for you

Comment: @SunilPachlangia, Can you provide an Example for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "best way" to search in this format. There is no way at all.

No wonder you have no clue how to do that. I'll tell you more - no one knows it either. Tags should never be stored in json format. It is like as if you built a car, placing wheels on the roof. And then come asking, how to drive it.

You have to learn database basics first. And then create your tables proper way. making a **separate table for tags.** Storing each on a separate row.  After that you will be able to search a tag usual way, using JOIN query to attach the corresponding records to the result.

```
$sql  = "SELECT a.* FROM articles a, tags t WHERE aid=a.id AND tag=?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($tag));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I didn't make this system, I wouldn't have gone this way either.. But my clients is asking me to make a search function, and that is what I have.. So I wanted to be sure there wasn't a way to do it, before rewriting his system.

Comment: Depending on how much entries you want to search for you could use WHERE LIKE queries. I've used it to search 5-6000 entries and it worked well. But you will get unprecise results because you dont have as many options as using fulltext search.

Answer (score 2):

You should create another table `tag` with fields `name`, `post_id`.
I believe that is the best solution to do a search feature.

If you do not have permission to create database table. It depends on how many posts you have. a few? hundreds or even more? If there is not a huge rows of your post table. You can fetch all of them and decode to PHP Array and then use string comparison.

Or maybe, you can give up the database way, just handling with a cache file. We're only need to write cache if user create/modify a post.

But you also can use the unreliable way, using `like` operator in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the MySQL fulltext index.
Take a look in the [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) and this [**Zend Developer article**](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/)

But you shouldn't use fulltext searching for many columns.
In one of my projects I worked around it by concatenating to be searched columns in a TEXT column and apply to the fulltext index on it.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple you can try using like query

```
SELECT *  FROM `post` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%html%';
```

In PHP Variable:

```
$tag = "html";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `post` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%'.$tag.'%'");
```